# How would one prove that the map $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle: (f,g) \mapsto \int_{a}^{b}f(t)g(t)dt$ is an inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

How would one prove that the map $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle: (f,g) \mapsto \int_{a}^{b}f(t)g(t)dt$ is an inner product?

We were taught to use this function for inner product related questions, but now we are being asked to prove it and I don't know where to start.

Thank you!

Comment: the b and a are the terminals, sorry I didn't know how to enter them!

Comment: This is a definition of an inner product. What is the question?

Comment: I edited your question by guessing your intention; if this is your question, check the axioms for a map to be an inner product.

Comment: You have to show it satisfies the defining properties, that is it's bilinear (sesquilinear in the complex case) and (if that is part of the definition you got) it's positve definite.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This came from the intuitive meaning of inner product.
Let $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are two vectors such that
$\vec{a}=a_1e_1+a_2e_2+.....\\  
\vec{b}=b_1e_1+b_2e_2+...$  where $e_1,e_2,...$ are basis.
Then their inner product can be difined as
$$\left(a,b\right)=a_1b_1+a_2b_2+....\\  
\Rightarrow\left(a,b\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_ib_i}$$
and assume $f(x)=a_i$ when $x=i$ and $g(x)=b_i$ when $x=i$ , and also if $n\rightarrow\infty$ , then we can replace summation by integration,
$$\left(f,g\right)=\int{f(x)g(x)dx}$$

Comment: Thank you! This makes perfect sense :)